# Serializing object to JSON - Get attribute Name from a field of serializing class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a ParameterInfo class.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ParameterInfo
{
        public Parameter Param { get; protected set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
        public string Name { get => GetCultureName(); }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
        public string Value { get => Param.AsString(); }
}
```

I need to serialize my class to the json in such a way:

```
{"PHY_MATERIAL_PARAM_EXP_COEFF2": 0.0}
```

I can only get this instead

```
  {
    "Name": "PHY_MATERIAL_PARAM_EXP_COEFF2",
    "Value": 0.0
  }
```

how can I do it using Newton Json with? I am looking for a way with highest performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write your custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm):

```
public class ParameterInfoJsonConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(ParameterInfo);


    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                    Type objectType,
                                    object existingValue,
                                    JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        var val = (ParameterInfo)value;
        writer.WritePropertyName(val.Name);
        writer.WriteValue(val.Value);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

And either mark class with `[JsonConverter(typeof(ParameterInfoJsonConverter))]` attribute or pass it to `JsonConvert`:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ParameterInfo(), new ParameterInfoJsonConverter())
```

Comment: Looks good, except it's missing the braces so not producing valid Json - you need to add `writer.WriteStartObject();` and `writer.WriteEndObject();` - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/nBIzwf